# StyleClass ignored

Tags: css, oracle, components, oracle-adf, skin

I'm facing a very strange issue with ADF. I add a custom class to a component via StyleClass, I inspect the site, it's there. But when I add its styling to the skin file, like this:

```
.mycustomclass{   font-size:20px; }
```

and run again the file, the component doesn't have the custom class that I've set, instead it has "x1ni" and it's going on as x1nk, x1nj, x1u.
So for some reason all the classes that are used get renamed in a form like that and of course are ignored by the CSS file. Any class that is not used is ok.

Can anyone explain what's the reason behind this issue and how can I fix it, to keep my custom classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to skin css compression/obfuscation.
You can disable this behavior by adding parameter to your web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <description>Disable obfuscation of CSS rules</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Although its recommended only for development cycle, so switch it back to **false** when you go production.

Comment: Thank you. Just another quick question, after it goes in production what are the chances for my classes to mess up in case some components are deleted or added and then put back into production. I mean how safe are the classes that he generates to not mix with others, in case the document components suffer changes.

Comment: Its safe if you define them in the skin and use only for ADF components. If you will play with the custom javascript/html includes it will fail. For this cases you should include separate css file and define rules there (of course you won't be able to refer skin rules there)

Comment: I guess it may be a bit confusing, give me some reallife code sample to make it more clear.